# How to set up parameters of a stored procedure in JMeter using a JDBC Request

Tags: stored-procedures, jmeter

I am planning to load the database using a stored procedure callable statement. The test plan I am creating in JMeter looks like below:

```
- Test plan
  - Thread Group
     - JDBC Connection Configuration
     - JDBC Request
     - View results tree
     - Summary Report
```

- **JDBC Connection Configuration** is based on tests that already work.
  The question is with my JDBC Request:
- **Variable name**: is the database name same as in JDBC Connection configuration
- **Query Type**: `Callable Statement`
- **Query:** `{call schema.dbpk_utilities.get_user_id(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}`
- **Parameter values:** `S12345, HR, OUT, NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL`
- **Parameter Types**: `VARCHAR, VARCHAR, INTEGER, VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR`
- **Variable names**: `username,hr, id, four, five, six, seven`

The error I get is:

```
Response message: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
"OUT"
```

Can anyone tell me why the response message? Is it possible to call Stored procedures in JMeter? I am struggling to OK this request!

Answer (score 2):

Following the 'no space rule' from the previous post I found out why the request was responding with java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "OUT" message. See below

**Variable Name:** Oracle

**SQL Query:** Callable Statament

**Query:** {call nspishr.dbpk_user_utilities.get_user_details(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}

**Parameter Values:** S12345,DMS,OUT,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

**Par Types:** VARCHAR,VARCHAR,OUT INTEGER,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR

**Variable names:** username,dms,id,four,five,six,seven

Notice how the parameters are registered in this call. In my procedure param 1 and param 2 are IN parameters. These are made IN parameters implicitly by giving them a parameter value S12345 and HR in my case.

From param 3 all the way to param 7 are OUT parameters. Param 4, 5, 6 and 7 have NULL values. Therefore no need to register them as OUT parameters. Param 3 (the id), however, is the OUT parameter and it has to be registered as such by explicitly saying OUT in the **parameter value** and then saying OUT INTEGER in the **parameter types** section. The thing to remember is that you need to specify OUT in both parameter value and parameter type. Not to forget the datatype of the parameter in the parameter types field. ie OUT INTEGER, OUT VARCHAR ...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to provide JMeter with a comma-separated list, I make sure there are no spaces before/after the commas.  I call this the 'no spaces' rule.

The poster sqeeky has also discovered this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170139/jmeter-passing-multiple-values-from-1-jdbc-to-another-jdbc), where sqeeky said:

> do NOT have any whitespace after the comma separating the parm names so instead of '${appid_1}, ${appid_2}' (where you can see there is a space separating the ParameterName values, specify ${appid_1},${appid_2} instead as the values in the ParameterName list - otherwise in this example ${appid_2} won't be included.

All three of your comma-separated lists (Parameter values, Parameter Types, Variable names) violate the 'no spaces' rule.  Try taking out all spaces in all three lists and trying again.

I checkout out [the doc](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) and unfortunately, I saw no references to the 'no spaces' rule, or perhaps the wording didn't reach out and grab me.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I tried the 'no spaces rule' but it didn't fixed my problem. I will certainly follow the no space rule from now on though! Thanks for the interesting link and the information provided