# Parallel execution of a stored procedure by using JMeter JDBC request and parameterization

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, jmeter, sql-server-2016

I am able to execute simple SQL queries in Jmeter by setting up thread groups,jdbc connection config, jdbc request,csv data config and view results tree. But the problem I am struggling with is to execute a SQL Server stored proc in parallel for 'n' different values.Could someone help me how to handle JDBC request with parameterization. I have gone through google many times and read through several articles but I didn't have any luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

**Stored Proc call :-**

```
exec Mydatabase.[dbo].[Mystoredproc] A=300,@ID=8,@C='COMBINERES',@Q=1,@Debug=0
```

For example, if I want to run the above stored proc call 40 times I will be having 1...40 in my csv file and read each value one by one and pass it to the @ID parameter in the sp call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread Group 50 threads. 0 ramp up

No CSV. Use ${__threadNum} instead of ID parameter in procedure.

It should call 50 parallel requests.

JDBC Configutation use Max Number of Connections 0.

JDBC Request query type  Callable Starement.

see [How to set up parameters of a stored procedure in JMeter using a JDBC Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839893/how-to-set-up-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-in-jmeter-using-a-jdbc-request)

Comment: What should I mention in the Query Type?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839893/how-to-set-up-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-in-jmeter-using-a-jdbc-request