# Testing a stored procedure in JMeter - format error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jmeter

I am trying to test an Oracle Stored Procedure in JMeter. I have already done the configuration to the DB successfully, but when I call the stored procedure and send the parameters, I have a format error, apparently, the JMeter is not sending the parameters as I configure them.

SP-JMETER:
[image: SP-JMETER]

This is the error:

ERROR:
[image: ERROR]

As you can see, the parameters reach the stored procedure, and it processes it, but apparently, I'm not sending them right.

In this way I execute the stored procedure in the PL/SQL Developer:

SP-PLSQLDEV:
[image: SP-PLSQLDEV]

And let me know if you need any more information.

```
w_trans_date: = substr (w_in, 1, 8); / * left (w_in, 8); */
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the code you are using to call the procedure as text (not images); details of the parameters you are using (again, as text); and the `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `CREATE PACKAGE` statement for your procedure. If we can't see the code we can't tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37839893/1509264

Comment: Have you tried `your_first_parameter,NULL,NULL` rather than `your_first_parameter,]NULL[,]NULL[`?

Comment: Also, you have declared it as an `INOUT VARCHAR` whereas in SQL Developer is it only an `IN` parameter?

Comment: Sorry but the SP code can't be published :(. 
this is how i call the stored procedure in JMETER: call INGRES.atm01atd(p_in => ?,
p_out => ?,
p_error => ?)

Comment: I have also tried to pass only NULL as a parameter, but it doesn't work

Comment: Also I have already tried the parameters like IN VARCHAR, it doesn't work either :(

Comment: There is an error in one of the string literals in your stored procedure. Specifically at line 219 (according to the image that you posted). Does this help: [SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542882/sql-error-ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string-01861/22543299) Since you claim that _the SP code can't be published_ I can't help you any more than that. Can you maybe post just line 219?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is line 219 of the code:
w_trans_date: = substr (w_in, 1, 8); / * left (w_in, 8); * /

But I think the problem is in how the JMETER sends these parameters, since if I enter these same values ​​in the PL / SQL Devoloper it processes it correctly.

Comment: Your statement `w_trans_date: = substr (w_in, 1, 8);` is apparently converting a string to a date. Therefore this will be a implicit conversion with oracle using the NLS_DATE_FORMAt as the expected string format. Try an explicit conversion:  `w_trans_date: = to_date( substr (w_in, 1, 8), 'mmddyyyy';` where 'mmddyyyy' represents your input date is formatted, change as needed for your specific values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to w_trans_date: = substr('28372873822327', 1, 8);
If this code will work properly, see on value in w_in variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding the following line to the INIT SQL STATEMENTS of the JDBC CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:

alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd / mm / yyyy'